# Getting issue while load CSV file and perform action using PySpark, jupyter notebook

Tags: csv, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
import os
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
%pylab inline
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--master local[2] pyspark-shell"
os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161'

# Spark Session builder
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
from pyspark.sql import Row

# Load the CSV file and make a RDD
linesRDD = sc.textFile("C:/PersonalWork/DataAnalysis/Data/compet/data/train.csv")

# Use the collect function to count the length of RDDs
linesRDD.count()
```

Once we execute any Action(example: count()) on linesRDD, I am getting error messages.
Even If I use the sparksqlcontect.read.csv("../train.csv") and after that want to do any action I am getting the same issue. 
Could you any one help to resolve the issue? 
Note : I am using PySpaprk, Jupyter notebook, windows7.
Issue details are mentioned below :

```
 Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-15-5f211be3c251> in <module>()
 ----> 1 linesRDD.count()

 C:\spark\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py in count(self)
 1039         3
 1040         """
 -> 1041         return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
 1042 
 1043     def stats(self):

 C:\spark\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py in sum(self)
 1030         6.0
 1031         """
-> 1032         return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
 1033 
 1034     def count(self):

 C:\spark\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py in fold(self, zeroValue, op)
904         # zeroValue provided to each partition is unique from the one provided
905         # to the final reduce call
--> 906         vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
907         return reduce(op, vals, zeroValue)
908 

C:\spark\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py in collect(self)
807         """
808         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 809             port =         self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
810         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
811 

C:\spark\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\spark\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
 61     def deco(*a, **kw):
 62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
 64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
 65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

C:\spark\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
320             else:
321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3.6": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 13 more

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2094)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:467)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3.6": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 13 more
```

​ 
Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`linesRDD=sc.textFile("C:/PersonalWork/DataAnalysis/Data/compet/data/train.csv")`

Try this:

`linesRDD=sc.textFile("file:///C:/PersonalWork/DataAnalysis/Data/compet/data/train.csv")`

Answer (score 0):

According to the stacktrace your system is not able to find your python binary in the path.

You could give spark a hint by setting `PYSPARK_PYTHON` to a valid python location